# How to get controller method in Observer in magento?

Tags: magento

I need controller method in Observer

My observer :

```
public function observer()
{
//need controller action here
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function adminAction()
    {
    //my action
    }
```

My questions

1. Is this possible to call controller method in observer in magento.
2. If yes please explain how?
   if no then is there any way to hit controller action through observer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can listen on dynamic events:

`controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()`
or
`controller_action_postdispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()`

You can find the dispatch of these events in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`

The method `$this->getFullActionName()` returns a string formed by `routeName_controllerName_actionName` so, assuming that your routeName is `myadminroute`, your controllerName is `mycontroller` and your action is `admin` (like your code) you can listen on the events:

`controller_action_predispatch_myadminroute_mycontroller_admin`
and
`controller_action_postdispatch_myadminroute_mycontroller_admin`

If you are in the admin area you can listen on:

`controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_myadminroute_mycontroller_admin`
and
`controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_myadminroute_mycontroller_admin`

in your observer class you can retrieve the action controller by doing:

`$observer->getControllerAction()`

**Example:**

Supposing you are in admin area:

```
<config>
    ...
    <models>
        <my_model_prefix>
            <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model</class>
        </my_model_prefix>
    </models>
    ...
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_myadminroute_mycontroller_admin>
            <observers>
                <my_event_unique_tag>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>my_model_prefix/observer</class>
                    <method>myObserverMethod</method>
                </my_event_unique_tag>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_myadminroute_mycontroller_admin>
    </events>
    ...
 </config>
```

in `Model/Observer.php`:

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function myObserverMethod($observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i need a favour from you, could you explain me this with example that how can i implement this with my observer.

Comment: I've added an example, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You can instantiate a controller anywhere with

```
$controller = Mage::getControllerInstance(
    'The_Controller_Class',
    Mage::app()->getRequest(),
    Mage::app()->getResponse());
```

To tell if this is the best way, I would need to know more about your use case, but it probably isn't. If you want to show a different page without redirecting, have a look at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_forward()`:

```
/**
 * Throw control to different action (control and module if was specified).
 *
 * @param string $action
 * @param string|null $controller
 * @param string|null $module
 * @param array|null $params
 */
protected function _forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $request->initForward();

    if (isset($params)) {
        $request->setParams($params);
    }

    if (isset($controller)) {
        $request->setControllerName($controller);

        // Module should only be reset if controller has been specified
        if (isset($module)) {
            $request->setModuleName($module);
        }
    }

    $request->setActionName($action)
        ->setDispatched(false);
}
```

Unfortunately this is protected so it can only be used from within a controller. But you can do the same from anywhere else. What is happening here:

1. The original request (available via `Mage::app()->getRequest()`) is backed up: `$request->initForward()`
2. The request object then gets modified with a different controller action and parameters.
3. The "dispatched" flag of the request is set to false. This way, after the current controller action is finished, the front controller will dispatch the request again with the now changed parameters.

If your observer is attached to an event that takes place before dispatching, it is sufficient to change the request parameters.

Comment: $controller = Mage::getControllerInstance('index','Mbyte_Pushnotification/Adminhtml_SqliteupdateController','Pushnotification');
I am getting the the below error:
 Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Mbyte/Pushnotification/Adminhtml/SqliteupdateController.php'

Comment: Which Magento version is this? The first parameter of `getControllerInstance` should be the actual class name, such as `Mbyte_Pushnotification_Adminhtml_SqliteupdateController`, no `/` in it.

Comment: Magento Version : 1.8.0.0

Comment: Now i added the code $controller = Mage::getControllerInstance('Mbyte_Pushnotification_Adminhtml_Sqliteupda‌​teController','Mbyte_Pushnotification/Adminhtml_Sqliteupda‌​teController','Pushnotification');

still the same error:

2014-10-02T06:55:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mbyte/Pushnotification/Adminhtml/Sqliteupda‌​teController.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home1/mercodec/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: The other two parameters should still be request and response exactly as in my answer.